# How to CPU throttle Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: hardware

I want to know how to throttle the CPU usage on my pi to lower the current draw. I have tried looking this up but I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Raspberry+Pi+set+cpu+frequency&ia=web

Comment: That will depend on which **model** of RPi you have. @joan's answer covers one technique for the RPi 4, and [the link](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#frequency-management-and-thermal-control) actually covers several models of RPi. Starting with the installation of `cpufrequtils`, and trying something should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: This is an exercise in futility. As in your previous questions the answer is to fix your power supply or use a less power hungry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

One method to try is setting `dvfs=2` in `/boot/config.txt`.

See [Pi4 frequency management](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#frequency-management-and-thermal-control).